单纯 vs 成熟 in the context of female
So, I watched a dating show from mainland on YouTube.  When a male guest was asked if he prefers 单纯 or 成熟 female.  He replied with 成熟 and immediately got rejected by all female guests, except one.4
What exactly do these two terms imply in a context of a female?

Quote:- "...got rejected by all female guests, except one"
Haha!
My favorite quote about women is "A woman's mind is cleaner than a man's: She changes it more often"
If those females who rejected him were to be asked again an hour later, the answer might well be different.
Jokes aside, and coming to the question at hand, is yet another quote, "The most beautiful thing women can wear is confidence" You'll know why later.
Now why is this second quote relevant to our question?
Because of the way men and women, (I hesitate to say Chinese men and women), view quite differently, 单纯 and 成熟
Here too we are up against the problem or difficulty in translation from one language to another because all languages are culture based which is a function of the values, norms, knowledge, beliefs, practices, experiences of a people.
Let's say the translation of 单纯 is "simple", "pure". How would people of different cultures interpret it?  or,
成熟 is interpreted as "mature", "ripe", even "aging"?
I don't think women in developed Western countries would want to be considered "simple" in the sense of "exhibiting childlike simplicity and credulity" which borders on naivety, which, however, in ancient times of olden conservative China was a good thing because it denotes a perceived lack of sexual experience.
Even today in ultra modern Japan we have the "Kawaii" culture which is Japanese aesthetics centered around the appeal of cuteness, characterized by childlike, charming qualities and playful elements, in females of course.
Now, how about "pure"? Well, no matter how one interprets this, it does not have much negativity, as "purity" could range form sexual innocence to having an honorable, salutary state of mind and therefore character, and so perhaps that is why most of the contestant women prefer to interpret 单纯 as pure and therefore be perceived as such?
Now the one woman who did not reject him showed both self-confidence borne out of being mature herself because perhaps she interpret 成熟, "matured", as someone who is developed and balanced in their personality and emotional behavior which is a good thing no matter one's age, and not as someone getting on in age, i.e. not "young"
It would be interesting to ask the man in question how he would interpret 单纯 & 成熟. I bet that if that had happened, some of the women might well change their minds.
Here is an experience I had from a close friend. He had a beautiful girlfriend once, but later broke off with her. When asked why, he said she, (perhaps too "simple" or lacking in "maturity"), just couldn't understand or appreciate his jokes and thus he found her boring, his exact words.

单纯 - Lack of sophistication in dealing with relationships (simple; pure).
成熟 - Fully developed or matured and ready to be eaten or used.
The male guest gives the impression that he is looking for "instant pleasure" rather than building a relationship with a girl who is "simple and pure" - a status most young girls prize themself for.

Both terms refer to personality in this context.
单纯: naïve, simple in outlook
成熟: mature, sophisticated
